# How to parse only the file name without the directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this:

```
File.Copy(AnimatedGifFiles[i], eventDir);
```

In `AnimatedGifFiles` that is `List<string>` I have file names, for example: `c:\temp\1.gif`
And `eventDir` is `c:\test`

Now I want to copy the file from the List to the `eventDir`.

Somehow I need to parse from the List only the file name and add the file name to `eventDir`.
So the `File.Copy` will be something like:

```
File.Copy(animatedGifFiles[i], eventDir+"\"+Filename);
```

So in `eventDir` I will have the file `1.gif`

The name of the file in `eventDir` should be the same name of the file in `AnimatedGifFiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to extract the file name from the path:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
```

You can then combine it with another directory name using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
```

Comment: downvoter, care to explain what's wrong in my answer?

Comment: It was there before your edit, so given that it was a functional, correct answer, I can only assume they were less than pleased with the fact that your entire answer was just a single line of code.